# Rename sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, rename

Im trying to rename a site collection by changing the url by using this PowerShell

```
$site = get-spsite -identity http://xxx:9000/sites/SCOne
$site.Rename("http://xxx:9000/sites/SCOneNew")
```

I got this message

> Exception calling "Rename" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot rename a site collection     with recycled items. Empty the site recycle bin of site collectio

The recycle bin is empty now but I still can't rename and I get the same message.

I have tried this PowerShell to get count of items in recycle bin

```
$site = get-spsite http://xxx:9000/sites/SCOne
Write-Host $site.RecycleBin.Count.ToString();
```

but it says

> you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: In your second script, you are using the new URL. You have not successfully moved it yest so you need to use the old URL `http://xxx:9000/sites/SCOne`. Also, the `.ToString()` is not necessary

Comment: i just wrote wrong, now its edited

Comment: Please ensure you are using your FARM ADMINISTRATOR account to perform this action.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're site is still listed as a SPDeletedSite?

[Get-SPDeletedSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx) & [Remove-SPDeletedSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286317.aspx)

You may already have used this site name before and deleted it. Check by running the following script:

```
>Get-SPDeletedSite
```

You'll see the site (or sites) listed, like this:

```
WebApplicationId   : 009c1289-392b-43a6-8222-146117074738
DatabaseId         : 88efc46f-5a2b-4171-81cb-7577da65bac3
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 86d69f7e-3a9e-4f65-8eba-550d77f93a18
Path               : /sites/collaboration
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/sites/collaboration
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-21 11:14:18

WebApplicationId   : c73bb367-d329-4ef2-aef7-323ce207d2a9
DatabaseId         : aeb2d6ab-9f9b-493f-aefc-797d4b591f43
SiteSubscriptionId : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
SiteId             : 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
Path               : /
Scheme             : Http
Url                : http://portal/
DeletionTime       : 2014-02-19 15:27:37
```

Copy the `SiteId` and run

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite –Identity 9d0ed313-0353-4cec-817a-a491a8c5fc26
```

That way you won't have trouble renaming the site if needed.

Comment: What!!  i havnt even deleted the site !!
The site still exists.

Comment: @Gästa, please keep a polite tone. We are trying to solve your problems, so try to treat us with respect

Comment: Sorry if it sounds unpolite. i mean just i was surprised
Förvånad

Comment: @Gästa No worries! What I mean is that the site with the name you're trying to rename to have already been used previously, and deleted before you came to the table. Just run the script Get-SPDeletedSite and see if this is an issue or not. It's just a sanity check minimizing the causes of errors you may have. :-)

Comment: i checked is, there is no deleted site with this name.
The problem is that i cannot remove the items by powershell.
when i delete items manualy from Recycle bin page, they dont be removed permanently i think they still exist somewhere. 
so the problem is in the deletion of the items in recycle bin

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here is what worked for me:

1) Empty the Site Collection Recycle Bin

2) On the left hand side of the Site Collection Recycle Bin page, you will see a link that says "Deleted from end user Recycle Bin"

3) Go to that link and empty the end user recycle bin, as well.

I was then able to rename the site.